# How c# wpf Button property name binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

This is My code.

`Button Name="{Binding menu_id}"`

I can't binding it with the field how can I do? Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You can't bind to the Name property of a Button or any other FrameworkElement.

Answer (score 1):

`Name` is what it is called and how you refer to it in your program. For example,

```
<Button x:Name="myButton"/>
```

You can then refer to your button by its name like this

```
myButton.Content = "Hello";
```

To set the button's content you need to bind to `Content` like this

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}"
```

And have a property like this

```
private string buttonText= "Hello";
public string ButtonText
{
    get { return buttonText; }
}
```

If you need to update your binding at any point you also need to implement [INotifyPropertyChange](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx). You might also want to look at your [binding options](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFBindingOptions.aspx) to decide what kind of binding you need.